# ddms error java.io.IOException in ANDROID

Tags: android, ddms

For what reason this error has come? And how do i solve this error????

[Error in console in eclipse]

```
[2015-07-07 11:45:09 - ddmlib] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
    java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.writeAndConsume(JdwpPacket.java:213)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:675)
        at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHeap.sendREAQ(HandleHeap.java:342)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Client.requestAllocationStatus(Client.java:521)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.createClient(DeviceMonitor.java:831)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.openClient(DeviceMonitor.java:799)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.processIncomingJdwpData(DeviceMonitor.java:759)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.deviceClientMonitorLoop(DeviceMonitor.java:648)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor.access$100(DeviceMonitor.java:44)
        at com.android.ddmlib.DeviceMonitor$3.run(DeviceMonitor.java:576)
```